# Android is skipping startActivityForResult, throwing Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I've ran into an infuriating issue with my Android development- whenever I call `startActivityForResult(this, Notepadv3.class);`, my app skipps directly over it, not launching the new activity nor returning any result from it. It's as if the code wasn't there!

When I change `this` to `mContext` (I have defined `mContext` as `Context mContext;` in the beginning of the class), the app crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

I have used the exact same code layout in a different class, and it runs flawlessly.
I've verified that I'm properly declaring the activities in the Manifest.

I've spent hours searching stackoverflow for answers, as well as looking up countless examples of how to do this particular activity, to no avail. I'm in the process of learning how to write Android apps, and as such have used Google's Notepad tutorial to base my app on. Thanks for the much appreciated assistance in advance!

Code and stack trace is as follows:

NoteEdit.java: (I've skimmed some irrelevant code for readability's sake)

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_item);

    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            barcode = (intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
            new updateBarcodeField().execute("");
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_NEW) {
        System.out.println("REQUEST_NEW onActivityResult().");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

private void saveState(){
    System.out.println("saveState()");
    doorCall();
    mDbHelper.open();
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String barcode = mBarcodeText.getText().toString();
    String price = mPriceText.getText().toString();
    Intent requestNew = new Intent(mContext, Notepadv3.class);

    if (returnCode == 1){
        System.out.println("returnCode is 1. Calling validateFields()...");
        String errors = validateFields(title);
        if (errors.length() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Need a title!", duration).show();
            System.out.println("Calling Notepadv3...");
            startActivityForResult(requestNew, REQUEST_NEW);
        }
    }

    if (returnCode == 2){
        System.out.println("returnCode == 2 - Cancelling activity");

    }else{
        if (title.matches("")){
            System.out.println("Variable is null. Returning...");
            doorCall();
            mDbHelper.close();
            return;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Checking mRowId for null");
            if (mRowId == null) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Success, product saved successfully", duration).show();
                System.out.println("Switching activity to 'NotesDbAdapter'");
                long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, barcode, price);
                mRowId = id;
            }else{
                System.out.println("mRowId is not null. Calling updateNote");
                mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, barcode, price);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("saveState() Finished");
    if (doorCall()==true){
        System.out.println("Database is Open");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Database is Closed");
    }
}

}
```

Notepadv3.java:

```
public class Notepadv3 extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButtonList);
    mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);        
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.addButton:
        createNote();
        break;

    case R.id.scanButtonList:
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);        

    }
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
        fillData();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

private void viewNote() {
    System.out.println("viewNote(). Starting NoteEdit...");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteView.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE, barcode);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    System.out.println("Notepadv3. requestCode is " + requestCode + ", and resultCode is " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            barcode = (intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
            System.out.println("Calling viewNote()...");
            viewNote();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER) {
        }
    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_NEW){
        System.out.println("Notepadv3. requestCode is REQUEST_NEW. Calling createNote()...");
        createNote();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
}
```

Stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.android.demo.notepad3/com.android.demo.notepad3.NoteEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3148)
at com.android.demo.notepad3.NoteEdit.saveState(NoteEdit.java:206)
at com.android.demo.notepad3.NoteEdit.onPause(NoteEdit.java:187)
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4590)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
```

Comment: Why do u need mContext? You are already within the activity so Why not use Activity_name.this itself

Comment: And what is doorCall(); Chances are that within saveState() some variable is null. Print variables to logcat and see what is returning null

Comment: Also, starting a new activity in `onPause()` looks dubious for me. (saveState() is called in onPause())

Comment: @Andy and OP Yes, I think the problem lies there, and mContext is not initialized. That itself will be null!

Comment: @Dya
I was using mContext to see if that changed anything... I'm not 100% sure how this 'context' stuff works, so I was trying different options. I had previously initialised mContext.
doorCall() is a a simple method that checks to see if the database is closed or not.

Comment: Why are you calling `startActivityForResult()` from `onPause()`? That can't be right. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Determining whether to save or abort the information entry, based on whether the title field has data in it or not. I realise this is a very stupid thing to be doing on an onPause() call, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you use mContext, you should initialize it in the onCreate method:

```
mContext=getApplicationContext();
//I recommend using the application context for avoiding memory leaks
```

Don't start an Activity from the onPause method.

Comment: Alright. So should I start it from a new method? And call this method in place of the existing code?

Comment: yes, as long as you don't call this method from the onPause method. That would have the same effect as starting the Activity directly :P

Comment: Wait a sec... where do you define the returnCode variable?

Comment: Ah, yeah. Me silly. And I defined returnCode just before onCreate()

This now brings me to the second issue; when using either `this` or `mContext` (initialised), the app simply ignores it.

Comment: Did you try starting the Activity outside the onPause method?
Use the getApplicationContext() instead of "this"

Comment: Yes, both of these things. I had my 'Submit' button directly call saveState()... the startActivity code is still ignored. Skips directly to the next if statement.

I forgot to mention that a few days ago, this was working flawlessly. I booted up my tablet to get up to speed on where I left it, and now it's playing up. Bug in the android framework? Or is my noobiness getting in the way of things?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where the problem is. Try exhaustive debugging and constantly looking at the LogCat... if you find something else, don't doubt to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!!

This won't be a fix for most that are looking for answers, but I hope I can point you in the right direction. As new as I am to Android (and Java in general), I am still totally convinced that this 'skipping' of code is, in fact, a bug.

However! As I'm calling `saveState()` from another activity, instead of launching a new intent that launches an activity from a separate class, which then launches an activity from the class where the first intent originated from, I simply replaced it with `return;`. Yeah- still quite derpy with learning the logic, but there it is. Simple, elegant, solution (well, simple and elegant compared to the horrendous code that existed before it :P)